# Swift 2 and Linux/OS X differences

Tags: linux, swift, swift2

I'm trying to port some basic app from OS X to Linux but it seems that even basic stuff is missing on Linux platform. Is there some documentation what is missing ??
Here is example:

```
exmcast.swift:7:20: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString'
let name: String = address.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "_")
```

This simple code works on OS X. On Linux - you see results.
It's very hard to port anything when there is no basic info what is missing.
And it looks like even basic stuff is missing..

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 will be released in fall 2016.

The recently open-sourced Swift and the Linux port are [work in progress](https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/):

> The port is still a work in progress but we’re happy to say that it is usable today for experimentation.

You can go to [Swift.org](https://swift.org) and [github.com/apple](https://github.com/apple) and enjoy the fantastic work.

When you find something not yet implemented, you can file a bug and/or help implement the feature.

New versions of the [open source Swift](https://swift.org/download/) will be posted regularly on Swift.org.

Answer (score 3):

The method you are trying to call is actually part of NSString. String is bridged behind the scenes to NSString and that is why you are able to use that method on OS X. NSString is part of the Foundation framework, and Foundation is not totally implemented for Linux. You can check the status of the various parts of Foundation here: [Foundation Status](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md). NSString is currently only partially implemented.

Comment: I didn't know about this status file. Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: No problem! So many new Swift goodies, it's hard to keep track of them all.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you still need to import Foundation

You are free to use pure Swift solution, in your case

```
    let str = "alfa.beta"
// (1)
    let str1 = str.characters.map {
        $0 == "." ? "_": $0
    }.reduce("") { (str, c) -> String in
        str + String(c)
    }
// (2)
    let str2 = String(str.characters.split(".").joinWithSeparator(["_"]))
    print(str,str1,str2) // alfa.beta alfa_beta alfa_beta
```

for something more advanced, you have powerful functions

```
mutating func replaceRange<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Character>(subRange: Range<Index>, with newElements: C)
```

or

```
mutating func replaceRange(subRange: Range<Index>, with newElements: String)
```